# Get latest Field from Firestore Collection using a Structured Query?

Tags: json, google-cloud-firestore, zapier

I am trying to use Zapier to add an email to a SendFox mailing list when a new user gets added to a specified Firestore path.  It's asking me for a structured query to find this data.
I am using the one that it's suggesting, but new users aren't being added correctly.  My concern is that the structured query isn't set up correctly.

My data is structured as follows:

```
- Customers (Collection)
   - [User ID] (Document)
      - EMAIL
      - Other Info
      - Other Info...
```

Whenever a new UserID document is added, I'm trying to access the email field in Zapier.

This is the current structured query:
[image]

```
   "orderBy": [{
       "field": {
           "fieldPath": "email"
       },
       "direction": "DESCENDING"
   }]
```

What is the correct structured query (json) to access the document I'm looking for?
To clarify, it's the latest document in the "customers" collection with the field "email".

I'm not looking fo any javascript code to get this data, merely the correct json structure for this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you have right now returns all documents from the `customers` collection in descending order of their email address, so with the `z`s first. That seems to be unlikely what you want.

Firestore has no built in concept of the most recent document, so what you'll want to do is:

1. Add a timestamp field to each document that you set to the current time (preferably a [server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp), but client-side will probably work too).
2. Sort the query on descending values of *that* new timestamp field.

Comment: That's so interesting because the Zapier docs say specifically that that format will return the newest document.
https://zapier.com/help/doc/common-problems-firebase

In any case, because I use the Stripe setup to add users to firestore automatically, I'm not quite sure how to add a timestamp...

Comment: Not sure where it says that, but at the top of the link you provide it says "The `orderBy` property in your query needs to ensure that the new documents are at the "top" of the search results, so that the Zap can see those documents." The only place where I imagine Zapier might automatically be able to get the new data is when using Firebase's Realtime Database wit push IDs, but that doesn't apply to Firestore (which you're using).

Comment: Ah, I understand.  Thank you for the reply.  I'm trying to use the `FieldValue.serverTimestamp`, but I'm getting an undefined error.
It looks like FieldValue is what's undefined and I'm not sure why.

I'm accessing firestore using a `getFirestore` reference from `firebase/firestore`.
This works for accessing and setting documents just fine, but for some reason FieldValue is null.
Any help would be appreciated.

And once I have the timestamp (maybe just using `Date.Now()` ), how would I query to get `email` sorted by `timestamp`?
Thanks!

Comment: As said, you can just start by using a client-side timestamp if that is easier to get working. Once it writes those values, use the field name that you write the timestamp in as the `fieldPath` argument.